# Asp.net dropdownlist Onselectedindexchanged event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, drop-down-menu

I have some dynamic controls in my asp.net page.

like,

```
TextBox ratingtxtbox = new TextBox();
ratingtxtbox.ID = "Rating_1";
```

and

```
DropDownList Exsecondpositiontxtbox = new DropDownList();
Exsecondpositiontxtbox.ID = "Exacta2nd_" + i.ToString();
```

For my textbox I'm added keyup event as

```
ratingtxtbox.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "ChangebyWin(" + i.ToString()+")");
```

Its perfectly working..

Now I added indexchanged event of dropdown list as

```
Exsecondpositiontxtbox.Attributes.Add("onselectedindexchanged", "ChangebyExacta(" + i.ToString() + ")");
```

But it not working.. Is it the error in Key name..?

Comment: You really need to share your javascript code as well. Also are you using `ClientIDMode=Static` on those controls? As that won't actually be the ID unless you are.

Comment: please try onchange instead of onselectedindexchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `onchange` instead. `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is a server-side event

```
Exsecondpositiontxtbox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ChangebyExacta(" + i.ToString() + ")");
```

Here is how you would use `OnSelectedIndexChanged`

```
Exsecondpositiontxtbox.SelectedIndexChanged += SomeEventHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Exsecondpositiontxtbox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ChangebyExacta(" + i.ToString() + ")");
```